# Java generics: is this a covariance issue?

Tags: java, spring, generics

I have a class like this:

```
public class MyClass<T>{
    private MyTape data;
    private List<T> someOtherdata;
}
```

I'm trying to write a generic service in Android usign Spring for Android RestTemplate, but this give a type mismatch:

```
ResponseEntity<MyClass<? extends Parcelable>> test = new ResponseEntity<MyClass<MyOtherType>>(..);
```

Where MyOtherType implements Parcelable. 
In there a way around this? My other solution is to use "less generic code" and subclass MyClass

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
 ResponseEntity<? extends MyClass<? extends Parcelable>>
```

instead of

```
 ResponseEntity<MyClass<? extends Parcelable>>
```